# Qt, LGPL, Android and GooglePlay licensing

Tags: android, lgpl, qt, android-market

So, you can build Qt apps and deploy them to android.

Taking a look at [this post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/10/01/benefits-of-the-indie-mobile-licensing/), I was wondering if making a game using Qt would be fine with LGPL legal terms given the following facts:

- The app would be at GooglePlay so, using third party libraries is a concern
- Source code for the app would be public
- Possible in-game purchasing. I don't really know if this is ok with making the code public, since I ignore what info is needed in the app for achieving this.

Would it be ok to use Qt LGPL license with all that? does any point fails at using LGPL? if so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, quoting from [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Licensing-talk-about-mobile-platforms):

> As Qt for Android uses the LGPL version of Qt, and it's perfectly
>   possible (and also recommended and supported) to dynamically link in
>   the Qt libraries when creating an app - there are no problems for app
>   developers using Qt for Android. The app developers can develop closed
>   source code and publish the app - no worries.
>
> Only if you statically link with the Qt libs could there be a problem
>   with closed source apps.

Answer (score 0):

The following libraries: Qt Location, Qt 3D, Qt Canvas 3D, Qt WebView, Qt Quick Controls and parts of Qt WebEngine are currently only available through LGPLv3, creating some serious responsibilities for the developer. As long as you don't use these and meet up with the rest of the minor requirements it's ok.

> "With LGPLv3 it is also explicitly stated that the user needs to be able to run the re-linked binary on it’s intended target device. It is your obligation to provide the user with all necessary tools to enable this process. For embedded devices, this includes making the full toolchain used to compile the library available to users. For parts licensed under LGPLv3 you are obliged to provide full instructions on how to install the modified library on the target device (this is not clearly stated with LGPLv2.1, although running the application against the modified version of the library clearly is the stated intention of the license)." - [FAQ](http://www.qt.io/FAQ/)

Comment: About Qt Quick Controls: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/licensing.html#licenses-used-in-qt and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/licenses.html#native-style-for-android It says Apache License 2.0 not LGPLv3

Comment: Not sure which info is fresher. Faq I linked mentions what I said listed.